# React Native Swipeable - How to shrink content instead of pushing content out of the view when swiping

Tags: react-native, react-native-gesture-handler, react-swipeable-views

I am using React Native Swipeable component from React Native Gesture Handler.

https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/api/components/swipeable/

**The original behaviour:**
When user swipe element right, it pushes content out of the view to display left menu.

**Current implementation**

[image]

**What I try to achieve:**
When user swipe element right, content width to be animated to display left menu, so the whole content is still visible to the user.

**UX Figma Design**

[image]

**My swipeable `Document.tsx` component**

```
import MkmIcon from './MkmIcon';
import StatusLabel from './StatusLabel';
import { ColorSchemeName, Pressable, StyleSheet, Text, TextStyle, useColorScheme, View, ViewStyle } from 'react-native';
import { Colours } from '../../assets/styles';
import { Swipeable } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { WINDOW_FONT_SCALE } from '../../services/DimensionsHelper';
import { setSwipeDemoSeen } from '../../redux/settingsSlice';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useLayoutEffect, useRef } from 'react';

type Props = {
    number: number,
    title: string,
    status: string,
    description?: string,
    date: string,
    value: number,
    onPress?: (number: number) => void,
    onSwipeRight?: (number: number) => void,
    onSwipeableClose?: (number: number) => void,
    showSwipeDemo?: boolean,
};

export default function Document({ number, title, status, description, date, value, onPress, onSwipeRight, onSwipeableClose, showSwipeDemo }: Props): JSX.Element {
    const theme: Style = getStyle(useColorScheme());
    const swipeableRef = useRef(null);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const onPressHandler = (): void => {
        if (onPress) {
            onPress(number);
        }
    };

    const onSwipeRightHandler = (): void => {
        if (onSwipeRight) {
            onSwipeRight(number);
        }
    };

    const onSwipeableCloseHandler = (): void => {
        if (onSwipeableClose) {
            onSwipeableClose(number);
        }
    };

    const renderLeftCheckBox = (progress): JSX.Element => {
        return (
            <View style={ theme.checkContainer }>
                <MkmIcon name='CheckThick' colour={ Colours.white.s100 } style={ theme.check } />
            </View>
        );
    };

    const Container = ({ children }): JSX.Element => {
        return (
            onSwipeRight && onSwipeableClose
                ? <Swipeable
                    ref={ swipeableRef }
                    containerStyle={ theme.swipeableContainer }
                    renderLeftActions={ renderLeftCheckBox }
                    onSwipeableOpen={ onSwipeRightHandler }
                    onSwipeableClose={ onSwipeableCloseHandler }
                    overshootLeft={ false }
                >{ children }</Swipeable>
                : <View style={ theme.container }>{ children }</View>
        );
    };

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        if (showSwipeDemo) {
            const swipeable: Swipeable = swipeableRef.current;

            setTimeout(() => {
                swipeable.openLeft();
            }, 1000);

            setTimeout(() => {
                swipeable.close();
            }, 2500);

            setTimeout(() => {
                dispatch(setSwipeDemoSeen());
            }, 3500)
        }
    }, [showSwipeDemo]);

    return (
        <Container>
            <Pressable style={ ({ pressed }) => [theme.documentContainer, (onPress && pressed) && theme.pressed ] } onPress={ onPressHandler }>
                <View style={ theme.row }>
                    <View style={ theme.column }>
                        <Text style={ theme.title }>{ title }</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View>
                        <StatusLabel status={ status } />
                    </View>
                </View>
                {
                    description &&
                    <View style={ theme.descriptionContainer }>
                        <Text style={ theme.description }>{ description }</Text>
                    </View>
                }
                <View style={[ theme.row, theme.rowBottom ]}>
                    <View style={ theme.column }>
                        <Text style={ theme.date }>{ date }</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View>
                        <Text style={ theme.amount }>£{ value }</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </Pressable>
        </Container>
    );
}

type Style = {
    container: ViewStyle,
    swipeableContainer: ViewStyle,
    documentContainer: ViewStyle,
    pressed: ViewStyle,
    row: ViewStyle,
    column: ViewStyle,
    title: TextStyle,
    descriptionContainer: ViewStyle,
    description: TextStyle,
    rowBottom: ViewStyle,
    date: TextStyle,
    amount: TextStyle,
    checkContainer: ViewStyle,
    check: ViewStyle,
};

const getStyle = (colourScheme: ColorSchemeName): Style => {
    return StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
            marginBottom: 16,
        },
        swipeableContainer: {
            padding: -1,
            marginBottom: 16,
            borderRadius: 4,
            backgroundColor: Colours.success.s100,
        },
        documentContainer: {
            padding: 16,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderBottomWidth: 4,
            borderRadius: 4,
            borderColor: Colours.grey.s30,
            backgroundColor: Colours.white.s100,
        },
        pressed: {
            opacity: 0.6,
        },
        row: {
            flex: 1,
            flexDirection: 'row',
            alignItems: 'center',
            alignContent: 'space-between',
        },
        column: {
            flex: 1,
        },
        title: {
            fontFamily: 'Montserrat_500Medium',
            fontSize: 14 / WINDOW_FONT_SCALE,
            lineHeight: 21 / WINDOW_FONT_SCALE,
            color: Colours.charcoal.s100,
        },
        descriptionContainer: {
            paddingTop: 8,
        },
        description: {
            fontFamily: 'Montserrat_600SemiBold',
            fontSize: 16 / WINDOW_FONT_SCALE,
            lineHeight: 24 / WINDOW_FONT_SCALE,
            color: Colours.charcoal.s100,
        },
        rowBottom: {
            paddingTop: 12,
        },
        date: {
            fontFamily: 'Montserrat_500Medium',
            fontSize: 14 / WINDOW_FONT_SCALE,
            lineHeight: 21 / WINDOW_FONT_SCALE,
            color: Colours.charcoal.s60,
        },
        amount: {
            fontFamily: 'Montserrat_700Bold',
            fontSize: 16 / WINDOW_FONT_SCALE,
            lineHeight: 24 / WINDOW_FONT_SCALE,
            color: Colours.charcoal.s100,
        },
        checkContainer: {
            paddingHorizontal: 12,
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
        },
        check: {
            width: 30,
            height: 30,
            padding: 7,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: Colours.white.s100,
            borderRadius: 15,
        },
    });
};
```